# Batch script to build a Python package using the Windows SDK

Tags: python, windows, build, winapi

I'm currently building 64-bit extensions on Windows following the instruction in *[Compiling 64-bit extension modules on Windows](http://wiki.cython.org/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows)*.

I want to script this, so I don't have to open the Windows SDK Command Shell every time I want to do this, so I have a batch file:

```
setlocal EnabledDelayedExpansion
CALL "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /x64 /release
set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
\path\to\python.exe \path\to\setup.py bdist --format=msi
```

However, I get these errors. How do I get `cl.exe` back on the path?

```
Could not locate executable cl.exe
Executable cl.exe does not exist
```

Fair warning, I know little about building extensions on Windows as is obvious from this post, so please suggest a better way if there is one.

**EDIT:** The original call to SetEnv.cmd does raise an error.

```
The x64 compilers are not currently installed.
Please go to Add/Remove Programs to update your installation.
.
Setting SDK environment relative to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0
.
The system cannot find the batch label specified - Set_x64
```

There are then some errors for various commands I use based on the system path (e.g., subprocess calls to git that it can't find git).

CL.exe is installed here at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe`. If I just open the Windows SDK Cmd Shell by the shortcut and install the usual way from here, it is found.

Comment: How did you take it off the path in the first place?

Comment: I didn't take it off the path. It's not available on the path in the batch file environment. I assume it happens by the call to the SetEnv.cmd. When running the Windows SDK Command Shell, it calls CMD.exe with the /K option, which I suspect has something to do with it. I don't know how to replicate such behavior in a batch file.

Comment: Christoph, I edited the original post with some more information.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, unfortunately, we have a bit of magic that checks for a C compiler and it does not detect a C compiler installing this way. Either I have to set compiler=mingw32 in distutils.cfg for 32-bit or install from the SDK environment. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/tools/_build.py#L24 Maybe I could uninstall VS and reinstall the SDK compiler?

Comment: If I set compiler=msvc in distutils.cfg. I get `error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat` which I do not have anywhere on my machine. See other comment thread.

Comment: Hmm, Odd. I don't recall ever installing VS in the first place. Everything I have, I should've gotten from following the instructions on the Cython wiki. I'll see if I can reinstall everything.

Comment: Ah, that's it. The culprit is that command is setlocal `EnableDelayedExpansion`. I'm an idiot. Thanks for your patience. I'll get their on windows eventually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity's sake. This works as expected. However, there's a typo in my batch file. If you replace the first line with

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Everything works as expected. The problem was that !PATH! wasn't being properly expanded in SetEnv.cmd.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is to use a Python script - it's much easier for me than a Windows batch script. You can use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module to call other programs, and it will keep you environment variables intact, unless you explicitly change them.

BTW, [Cython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cython) is not the only way of compiling Python to an EXE file. You can use a tool like [cz_freeze](http://readthedocs.org/docs/cx_freeze/en/latest/) too, which I think is slightly easier if you don't need the other features of Cython.

Comment: cx_Freeze is not a compiler. It is a packager. Modules built with Cython run 10-100 times faster than modules that are packaged with cx_Freeze.

Answer (score 0):

If Visual Studio is installed in your system, add a step in your batch script to run `vcvarsall.bat`. For ex if Visual Studio 2010 is installed, this batch file should be present in

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat",
```

or which ever drive you have installed Visual Studio, provided you did not override the default installation location.

Comment: I don't have vcvarsall.bat. I have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\vcvars64.bat`, but adding a call to it did not seem to fix the problem.